# Foreign driver gets a ticket in my car

Tags: legal, driving, california

A German friend came to visit in L.A.  He used my car and ran a red light. After he left the US, I received a letter with a ticket and fine. If I give the traffic dept. his name and address will they contact him in Germany?

Comment: Why just not pay the fine and ask your friend to pay you back? If he scratched your car you will do the same, is it?

Comment: I don't know about the US but, in the UK, it is not that simple.  You would get points on your licence.   Too many points and you lose your licence.

Comment: badjohn is correct here. Also in California, running a red light will add a 'point' to the driver's record. Taking the blame for someone else is not a good idea in this situation.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi In addition, getting points on your license can also increase your insurance rates - which is then an extra cost the OP has to bear.

Comment: Where I live, any tickets associated with cameras where you can't be sure who was driving are money only, no points, precisely because you can't be sure (including getting a friend to take the blame for you so that you don't go over a points threshold) who was driving, as you can when an officer issue the ticket in person.

Comment: @KateGregory In the UK the 'registered keeper' has to name who was driving the car (who then would be able to submit evidence it wasn't them, if they wanted). If they fail to do so, they can be convicted of failing to identify the driver.

Comment: @MJeffryes Indeed, and taking the blame for someone else is quite a serious offence which can lead to a prison sentence (e.g. former cabinet minister Chris Huhne https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Huhne )

Comment: @badjohn why would you get points on your licence?  You are required by law to identify, as far as is reasonably possible, the driver committing the offence.  The OP has done that.  Now, the powers that be will almost always follow it up by asking for evidence that the named driver was insured to drive the car and as long as the OP hasn't named a random foreigner he/she has fulfilled his/her legal obligations.

Comment: @TimRichards I should have made it clearer that I was referring to Giacomo's suggestion rather than the OP.  If the owner accepts the ticket then he will get the points or maybe some other charge if the authorities figure out the deception.

Comment: You said the friend visited LA. Is it a ticket from LA county? or some other county?

Comment: I hesitate to suggest this, with so much contention going on, but this question should perhaps be asked in [law.se], if properly reworded.

Comment: Read the ticket that you received, or info that came with it. Are there not instructions on what to do in case it was not you driving the car? I'm in Ireland but I'd have assumed it's the same in most places - I received a speeding ticket for a car I had just sold (but the change of ownership form obviously had not yet been processed). There were clear instructions on what to do if I had not been the one driving.

Comment: @djr - not forgetting Constance Briscoe.

Answer (score 24):

If you get a real ticket with the court's information (rather than a so-called "snitch ticket" from the camera company), you should plead not guilty by reason of identity mismatch. You cannot be found guilty or otherwise have any penalty for being the owner of the car, if you were not the driver. You absolutely do NOT have to disclose who the driver was. (If the form asks you to disclose, simply refuse to disclose; the worst outcome is you have to go to court (or do trial by written declaration, if allowed) and plead not guilty, and be found not guilty.)

In California, red light camera tickets are treated like other moving violations, which are criminal cases (i.e. criminal courts have jurisdiction). The burden of proof is on the prosecution, to prove that the defendant charged is guilty "beyond a reasonable doubt", which requires proving that the person charged was the driver "beyond a reasonable doubt". If you are charged, and the picture does not clearly show your face, the prosecution cannot prove their case, and you must be found not guilty. You don't need to prove, or even claim, that the driver was not you, to be found not guilty -- the burden of proof is on the prosecution, so it is they who have to prove that you were the driver to have you found guilty.

As the defendant in a criminal case, you always have the right to not testify in your own trial, so you cannot be forced to answer questions like, whether you were the driver, or who was the driver. (So, in fact, even if you were actually the driver, if the picture does not clearly show your face, you can still do the same thing of pleading not guilty, declining to testify, and be found not guilty if the prosecution cannot prove it was you beyond a reasonable doubt. You would not have committed perjury since you would not have testified that it was not you.)

In some other jurisdictions, there is a fine imposed on the owner of a vehicle that ran a red light camera, and the only way to escape the fine is to disclose who was the driver. But there is no such thing in California. There is no provision in California law that provides for a fine or other penalty on the owner of the car for a red light camera violation, other than on the driver who is found guilty of (or pleads guilty to) the violation.

Comment: A Note: Simply asserting that it wasn't you driving your own vehicle when the infraction happened, without providing an alternative identity for the person driving does not necessarily create reasonable doubt.  If it did, traffic camera tickets would be virtually unenforceable, and abandoned as a waste of the court's limited time & resources.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141021/discussion-on-answer-by-user102008-foreign-driver-gets-a-ticket-in-my-car).

Answer (score 11):

IANAL and this is not legal advice.

A quick google of "california friend ran red light in my car" turned up a lot of lawyers websites that seem have the same basic information.  [This one](https://www.wklaw.com/practice-areas/fight-traffic-ticket-california/red-light-camera-tickets/)  (choose at random) states (my emphasis):

> California law states that the driver cited for a traffic violation is
> liable for the ticket, not the vehicle’s owner. However, if your
> vehicle is captured running a red light by a red light camera, the
> ticket will be mailed to your address. Thus, **if you receive a red
> light camera ticket in the mail but you were not the person driving,
> you should hire an attorney to challenge the ticket**.

and

> If a friend or family member was driving your car, the Judge might ask
> you to identify the person in the photograph. It is important to note
> that you are not legally required to provide this information to the
> Judge. A knowledgeable traffic attorney should notify you of this and
> should raise this argument in traffic court. Thus, your ticket may be
> dismissed and the police agency will then have the burden of
> identifying the driver by matching the red light camera photo to their
> driver’s license records. If the police agency is successful in
> identifying the driver, they will send the citation to said person via
> mail.

So it comes down to how you want to spend your money, and if you can get money out of your friend.  But basically, if you want to avoid points, and insurance costs you need to contest the ticket and go to court.  In a case like this I would suggest contacting a bunch of lawyers who specialize in traffic violations in California, and get an idea as to how much it will cost you.  Then you can make a reasonable plan about where and how to spend your money.  I would also be informing your friend about all of this and seeing how much of a "friend" they are.

Finally, Note that all these websites I saw want you to hire *them*.  I'm not promoting any of these sites, and you should make your own choice.

Comment: I would honestly take it with a grain of salt if a lawyer would recommend me to hire a lawyer do achieve something. I have no idea about US or Californian legal requirements, but handling a traffic violation ticket where the driver is not the vehicle owner is such a common and likely trivial situation, that I find it hard to believe that it is in any way required or even recommended to have a lawyer dealing with the situation for you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141022/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-m-foreign-driver-gets-a-ticket-in-my-car).